# Cache images with picasso + okhttp

Tags: android, image, caching, picasso, okhttp

I'm using picasso + okhttp to load and cache images.

Currently this code is working as I expect and the cache is working as I want it to.

```
Picasso.with(Context).load("http://images.com/image.png").into(ImageView);
```

I want to download images on a initial synchronization, so I tried this code:

```
Picasso.with(Context).load("http://images.com/image.png");
```

But it is not working. The request (from the okhttp lib) is made in the function [into(ImageView)](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.java).

How can I cache the image to use it later with Picasso or okhttp?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just for future reference, I solved the problem with:

```
Picasso.with(Context).load("http://images.com/image.png").fetch();
```